# Kendo UI Mobile ListView filter

Tags: filter, kendo-ui, kendo-listview

I've been using kendo for quite some time but there is a issue that I'm facing using kendo filter in kendo list view. I am developing a SPA using kendo UI. In one of the views I've implemented kendo filter using http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile-listview/filtering link. The filter works fine on writing any input but when I re navigate to that view again it displays two filters. What can be the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, make sure you render the kendo mobile listView only once. If not, kendoMobileListView() will add another input each time you'll use 
$("#list").kendoMobileListView() .

If you have to render the listView on pageShow event, make sure you remove additionnal filter inputs with:

```
$("#your-view form:not(:first)").remove();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I made it possible, I check its already rendered than do not create it again else create it. The whole thing check by Boolean value true or false